# Sympy Lambda performance when using Sum

Tags: python, sympy

I have a cost function defined like this which I'm looking to minimize over the variables `atilde`, `d` and `c`. `y` and `vtilde` are arrays of (transformed) observations.

Note that I need to minimize it many times as it is the solution of a reduced problem (the larger problem involves two more variables which appear through the transformed observations). Hence the performance is important.

```
atilde, d, c, i, n, lamda = symbols('atilde d c i n lamda')
y = IndexedBase('y')
vtilde = IndexedBase('vtilde')

term = (atilde + d * y[i] + c * sqrt(y[i] ** 2 + 1) - vtilde[i]) ** 2
cost_fn = Sum(term, (i, 0, n - 1))
```

From that function, with or without substitutions on boundaries, I compute a gradient and solve it symbolically (a total of 19 solutions for inside the domain and all faces/edges boundaries). I then want to compute these solutions for given numerical values of observations.

I'm stuck on achieving good performance because of the following:

- `lambdify` works but will not perform well as the `Sum` term which could and should be written as numpy `sum` is expressed as a loop (I think)
- not my preferred solution but `cython`, `C` fails as `Sum` is not implemented
- `ufuncify` fails for the same reason as above
- I couldn't find a way to automatically CSEing the 'constant' terms that depends on `y` and `vtilde` so I could manually write their lambdas/functions using numpy.
- I think I could manually rewrite the python code for the lambdas but I couldn't find a way to print fully expressed python code.

So only solution I see is to manually CSEing or coding the python functions for the 19 solutions.

I feel this should be a common enough case that I must be overlooking a way to do this better.

PS: test for lambdify not using numpy vectorisation:

```
n = Symbol('n')
x = IndexedBase('x', shape=(n,))
i = Symbol('i')  # For lambdify, the index needs to be a Symbol

expr = sqrt(Sum(x[i]**2, (i, 0, n - 1)))

syfn = lambdify([DeferredVector('x'), n], expr)
npfn = lambda x: np.sqrt((x**2).sum())

obs = np.arange(500)

%timeit syfn(obs, len(obs))
# 279 µs ± 15.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit npfn(obs)
# 7.37 µs ± 277 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned [ufuncify](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html#ufuncify), which is meant to speed up array computations.

Comment: Indeed, I tried it as well and forgot to mention it. It has the same issue as `cython` or `C`, `Sum` is not implemented. Edited for completeness

Comment: Right, but you could use ufuncify to compute the array "terms" without a loop, and then sum it with NumPy's sum method.